# Composer Not Getting Latest Version of Module

Tags: composer, community-official-site

I am one of the maintainers of [Bootstrap Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_paragraphs). The module is currently set as the 2.0 branch to be the default and the 1.0 branch is set to unsupported.  The 1.0 had a Beta Release but the 2.0 is currently in Alpha.

When I run `composer require drupal/bootstrap_paragraphs` composer downloads the 1.0 release (`"drupal/bootstrap_paragraphs": "^1.0@beta",`) instead of the 2.0 release.

What do we have to do to make the 2.0 branch be downloaded when running `composer require drupal/bootstrap_paragraph`.  Want to avoid as many people as possible from using the 1.0 branch.

Comment: It seems there is no composer.json file in your 2.x branch. I'd start with adding that.

Comment: @Neograph734 I was under the impression that Drupal.org adds the composer.json file and we didn't have to add it.

Comment: "If a contributed project maintainer wishes to add a dependency on a packagist library that is not hosted on drupal.org, they can add a composer.json file to their contributed project.

Most contrib developers do not need to do this as long as their drupal.org dependencies are expressed in their .info.ymlfiles."

Comment: The listing of dependencies is optional, true, but as far as I know do systems like packagist use the composer.json file also to load metadata about the project (description, authors, support pages). For those things you still need a composer.json file. Try adding it, I think it would help. There is such a file in your 1.x branch and that gets detected...

Answer (score 2):

Composer does not default to the "latest" it defaults to the "Most stable" when there isnt a stable release. In this case 1.0-beta1 is "more stable" than 2.0-alpha1.